# (Woocommerce) Add Words to Prices Display Everywhere but the Cart and Checkout Pages

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to add something before the price products category/ single-procut page only. I use this code as example:

```
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
    $price .= ' Starts At';
    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
```

But it shows up as "RM49.00 Starts At"
I need the words to be before the price. How do I achieve this?
I really need help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to append it before the price html. And you can check for single product page using `is_product()` and category page using `is_product_category()`.

```
    function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {

        if ( is_product() || is_product_category() ) {
           return 'Starts At ' . $price;
        }

    return $price;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. This did it. I just add in 'add_filter' and all good to go. You're a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
$price .= ' Starts At';
```

is shorthand for:

```
$price = $price . ' Starts At';
```

So, output of `RM49.00 Starts At` is entirely expected.

This is a common motif in many programming languages (but certainly not all).  For example, you will see things like:

```
count += 4
```

which means:

```
count = count + 4
```

You will also see `*=`, `/=`, `-=`, etc.